# Lex/Flex - Split the phone number Up?

Tags: c, regex, lex

I am making a program which got to split the phone-number apart, each part has been divided by a hyphen (or spaces, or '( )' or empty).

`Exp: Input: 0xx-xxxx-xxxx or 0xxxxxxxxxx or (0xx)xxxx-xxxx
    Output: code 1: 0xx
            code 2: xxxx
            code 3: xxxx`

But my problem is: sometime "Code 1" is just 0x -> so "Code 2" must be xxxxx (1st part always have hyphen or a parenthesis when 2 digit long)

Anyone can give me a hand, It would be grateful.

Comment: In the case where Code1 is only 2 digit long, do you always have an hyphen or a parenthesis ? (i.e., when there is no separator, is Code1 always 3 digit long ?)

Comment: nothing at all, Im still working on it.

Comment: @Ploutox Yeah, they always have hyphen or a parenthesis when 2 digit long.

Comment: Can you have parenthesis anywhere in your number ? is `(012)(3456)(7890)` valid or are parenthesis only for the first group ? Can you have `(012)-xxxx-xxxx` (with an hypehen after the parenthesis)? Will you test your regex against wrong formated numbers, or will you just use it to extract data from properly formated numbers ?

Comment: Are you just doing US numbers?

Comment: No, @Ploutox. Each part can only be divided by 1 kind of separator. And parenthesis is only for the first one. Fortunately, there is no wrong formated input in the function. Sorry for my question has been missed so much infor.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, the following regex will extract the information you need

```
^\(?(0\d{1,2})\)?[- ]?(\d{4,5})[- ]?(\d{4})$
```

Break down:

- `^\(?(0\d{1,2})\)?` matches `0x`, `0xx`, `(0xx)` and `(0x)` at he beggining of the string
- `[- ]?` as parenthesis can only be used for the first group, the only valid separators left are space and the hyphen. `?` means 0 or 1 time.
- `(\d{4,5})` will match the second group. As the length of the 3rd group is fixed (4 digits), the regex will automatically calculate the length of the Group1 and 2.
- `(\d{4})$` matches the 4 digits at the end of the number.

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/qF6vV3/3)

You can the extract data from capture group 1,2 and 3

**Note**: As mentionned in the comments of the OP, this only extracts data from correctly formed numbers. It will match some ill-formed numbers.